# detecting javascript dialog box when running coded ui test

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, dialog, coded-ui-tests

I'm running a coded ui test from visual studio. I've created a library that performs actions according to the type of controls.

For instance, if the control is a button, I do the following:

```
if (myButton.Id.CompareTo(Id) == 0)
{
    Mouse.Click(myButton);
}
```

Now, sometimes clicking a button opens up a javascript dialog box to confirm the click. I don't know in advance which buttons trigger a dialog box, so I'd like to know how I can detect there is one. Then I'd just do that sort of thing:

```
UIMapInfo.PerformDialogAction(BrowserDialogAction.Ok);
```

Does anyone know how to detect there is a dialog box ?

Comment: I am having the same issue and stumbled upon this page which (sort of) has some answers:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsautotest/thread/a9c151dc-7f3e-4750-bb5d-37a34d1767a6/